# What is the path of the `overrides.yaml` visible from Python code with Hydra

Tags: fb-hydra

Example of the code:

```
@hydra.main(config_path="./configs", config_name='example_01.yaml')
def main(hparams):
   # ...
   # What is the actual path of the `overrides.yaml`  file ???
   fn = ''
   tracker.log_artifact(fn)
```

I tried

```
def main(hparams):
    # ...
    p = Path(os.getcwd())
    print(p, p.exists())
    print([fn for fn in p.glob('**/*')])

    p = Path.cwd() / '.hydra/overrides.yaml'
    print(p.exists())
```

Output:

> ./outputs/2020-07-29/19-35-52 True
> [ ]
> False

But after the script is complete, I see that the files exist in the directory ./outputs/[date]/[time]/.hydra:

> config.yaml
> hydra.yaml
> overrides.yaml

Versions:
python:         3.6.9
hydra-core:     1.0.0rc1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the bugfixes in [1.0.0rc2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/releases/tag/v1.0.0rc2).

You should upgrade.

You can also access this information directly via the Hydra config:

```py
@hydra.main(config_name="config")
def my_app(_cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    print(HydraConfig.get().overrides.task)
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.